# Git have --no-prefix as the default?

Tags: git

We are using code collab and have to put the entry --no-prefix each time. Sometimes people forget and then they have to resubmit their code review. Is there a way to globally set the --no-prefix option so that the a/ b/ prefixes are never used?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yep. Set the config option `diff.noprefix`:

```
$ git config --global diff.noprefix true    # All repos
$ git config diff.noprefix true             # Current repo
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `diff.noprefix` to easily select filenames on screen. However found [Yelp pre-commit](http://pre-commit.com/) couldn't re-apply generated patches as they had the toplevel directory removed. *(Took me a while to figure that out!)*

So rather than modifying the actual `git diff` command, create a `di` [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```
git config --global alias.di 'diff --no-prefix'
```

Comment: pre-commit maintainer here :)  This was a bug -- as far as I can tell it got  (unintentionally) fixed in 0.16.0 (~2017-08-01) as part of [this patch](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/pull/571)